# Parallel downloading multiple files from azure storage and create zip file

Tags: azure, .net-core, parallel-processing, zip

I have a **Background Worker Process**, where I need to download **multiple files** from Azure Storage and then create a **ZIP file** with those files. All the process will be done in **memory**.

So, I created the below code.

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(1, 1);
ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };

using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(supportingDocLists, options, supportingDoc =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(supportingDoc.FileURL) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(supportingDoc.FileName))
            {
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(supportingDoc.FileURL);
                
                if (blobClient.Exists())
                {
                    BlobDownloadInfo downloadInfo = blobClient.Download();

                    // Store it in the zip file sequentially.
                    //semaphore.Wait();
                    
                    ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(supportingDoc.FileName);
                    lock(zipEntry)
                    {
                        using (Stream entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                        {
                            blobClient.DownloadTo(entryStream);
                        }
                    }                                    
                }                                
            }
        });
    }

    zipStream.Position = 0;
    return zipStream.ToArray();
```

But the code is not working properly. I am having the exception (**Cannot access a closed stream**). Can anyone help me to resolve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Put two last lines of code into `using (MemoryStream zipStream =  ...)` code block.

Comment: @Ryan problem is happening in this line: ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(supportingDoc.FileName);

Comment: Locking on zipEntry doesn't make sense, cause of it's some sort of thread-local variable - it doesn't prevent code from being executed concurrently. As a result, it leads to executing this peace of code when stream is probably being disposed.

Comment: So, my recommendation  is to use one of two options: - 1) Rewrite parallel foreach to sequential foreach. 2) Using of shared object `object locker = new object()` and use it inside Parallel.Foreach instead of thread-local. First options is preferred, cause of lock usage is a wasting of concurrency.

Comment: And i would rather move those two lines inside of most external `using` block.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the suggestion. I moved the last two lines inside the using (MemoryStream zipStream =  ...). Now the exception is gone but the method is returning Zero (0) byte now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue you're facing with the "Cannot access a closed stream" exception is because you're using the `using` statement to dispose of the `ZipArchive` and `MemoryStream` objects before accessing the zip stream again to convert it to an array. Once you exit the `using` blocks, the streams are automatically closed and disposed.

To resolve this issue, you can move the conversion of the zip stream to an array inside the `using` block for `ZipArchive`. Here's an updated version of your code:

```cs
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(1, 1);
ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };

using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(supportingDocLists, options, supportingDoc =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(supportingDoc.FileURL) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(supportingDoc.FileName))
            {
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(supportingDoc.FileURL);

                if (blobClient.Exists())
                {
                    BlobDownloadInfo downloadInfo = blobClient.Download();

                    ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(supportingDoc.FileName);
                    lock (zipEntry)
                    {
                        using (Stream entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                        {
                            blobClient.DownloadTo(entryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Move the conversion of the zip stream to an array inside the using block
        zipStream.Position = 0;
        return zipStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

By moving the conversion of the zip stream to an array inside the `using` block, you ensure that the stream is still open and accessible when performing the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the exception is gone. but It returns 0 byte.

Comment: MauriceMoss - Your seven answers this month appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.